# Syntastic error and warning symbols

Tags: vim, syntastic

I have syntastic plugin running correctly in vim. I just want to customize it a little more, I am trying to set the properties 'syntastic_warning_symbol' and 'syntastic_error_symbol' to differentiate them.

In my .vimrc I have:

```
let g:syntastic_warning_symbol = 'WW'
let g:syntastic_error_symbol = 'EE'
```

But when I open vim, I see 'EE' even in the Warning lines.

Am I doing anything wrong? It could be a bug, if so I will report to the developers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it works fine on my computer, can you post an example?

Comment: Hi gokcehan, I am using it with Python and flake8, maybe that influences. What language are you trying?

Comment: I was trying with `C`, does that work for you?

Comment: Nop, I am having the same behavior with C.

Comment: by default errors and warnings have different colors. what happens when you don't set anything?

Comment: I didn't know that the errors and warnings were shown in different colors. If I don't set anything, I see the symbol ">>" in the same color for errors and warnings. Is that what made me try to change the characters. By the way, I am using Vim 7.3 and the last syntastic git version.

Comment: you can check the screenshot in [github page](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic), there are red and yellow colors for errors and warnings respectively. I see you already opened a new issue there. you can also post your example C code in here so I can try it out as well..

Comment: Thanks for your interest gokcehan, many years ago I do not program in C (in the university I think), but [here](http://gallifrey.es/vim_screenshot.png) you can see a screenshot for an example code. As you can see in the status line, the word "aviso" is telling me that is a warning ("aviso" means warning in spanish), but is showing the same chars and colors to mark it. Tell me if am I wrong with the example code.

Comment: I tried your code and I can confirm that there is something wrong with your plugin. let's see what they say in github.

Comment: I have been talking with the developer and I have made a pull request. Thanks gokcehan.

Comment: glad to hear you made it. you can put an answer here and accept it to close the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a syntastic issue. I have been talking with the developer, and I have made a pull request in github. [Here are the issue and the pull request](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/391)